# new aptana 3/titanium studio new project glitch

Tags: titanium, aptana

Hello I recently noticed like 2 days ago that every time I create a new php , rails or any new project for that matter, I create the project successfully but after like 5 seconds of creating the project there is a [master] and a * next to it. For example a project I created before normally in the project explorer is fuel_intro, but now if I create a new project I have something like *fuel_project[master]. I have been trying to fix this problem for 2 days now. It is annoying because my files are in red color like if it was a bundle.So does anyone know why I am getting this?

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the GIT repository it creates internally.

Therefore, you have a version control on your own computer and that does actually make sense. (always use version control).

Not sure how you could disable this, but you could actually go along with it, and just commit the files you have changed. Once committed it will not be red anymore.

If you go to the menu and select preferences. Type there `git` and see what options you have. Good luck!

Comment: This worked for me. Look in Preferences under Team and you will find Git options. Aptana Studio automatically adds support for projects added with git repositories, so just uncheck that box.

Answer (score 1):

Topener's reply covered the reason.  Just want to add that if you want to turn off the git decorations, you could go to **Preferences** > **General** > **Appearance** > **Labor Decorations** and uncheck **Git Decorator**.